# Spring oxm marshalling and unmarshalling a list of objects

Tags: java, xml, spring, marshalling

We are using Spring for a project, and I need to marshall and unmarshall lists of objects 
from and to XML. 
The business objects themselves do not have @XmlRootElement annotations on them for various reasons, which cannot change.

I can do this easily with javax.xml by using a wrapper class. I'm using a simple testObject with a numeric ID and a description field:

```
/**
  * testObject for xml convert
  *
  */
package xmlconvert;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

//import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
//import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
//import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
//import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
//import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
//import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

public class testObject
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public testObject()
    {
        setObjectid( 0L );
        setDescription( " " );
    }

    public testObject( Long oid, String desc )
    {
        setObjectid( oid );
        setDescription( desc );
    }

    private Long objectid;

    public Long getObjectid()
    {
        return this.objectid;
    }
    public void setObjectid( Long oid )
    {
        this.objectid = oid;
    }

    private String description;

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription( String d )
    {
        this.description = d;
    }

}
```

My wrapper class looks like this:

```
/**
 *  JAXBToList
 * 
 *  An object that holds the list of objects to convert.
 *
 */
package xmlconvert;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import xmlconvert.testObject;

@XmlRootElement(name="testObjects")
public class JAXBToList
{
    protected List<testObject> list;

    public JAXBToList()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<testObject>();
    }

    public JAXBToList( List<testObject> list )
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="testObject")
    public List<testObject> getList()
    {
        return (List<testObject>) this.list;
    }

}
```

When I convert an ArrayList of these objects to XML, the code looks like this:

```
  @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="testObject", 
                          type=testObject.class)
  })
  public static void convertListToXML( JAXBToList objectList, 
                                            String xmlFilePath )
              throws IOException, JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( JAXBToList.class );
        marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,  Boolean.TRUE );
        marshaller.marshal( objectList, 
                            new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream(xmlFilePath) ) );
  }
```

I would like to use Spring marshaller and unmarshaller to do this, but there  seems to be no way to set the context to use the JAXBToList class in the oxm class `Jaxb2Marshaller`, or the other varieties of marshallers.

I know there is a set Jaxb Context Properties method, but there are no instructions on what I would need to set, or if using this would do the same thing as setting  the jaxb Context as shown above.

Does anyone have a link that illustrates how oxm may be used for a list of objects? A google search does not turn up much.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: hi Jimbo.  You can find my question in the last code box:  Does anyone have a link that illustrates how oxm may be used for a list of objects?
A google search does not turn up much.

Comment: I can't help you personally Tom, but I've moved your question outside of the code box so it's clear what your problem is. If you think you can edit this further (so that people can understand your problem more readily and therefore be in a better position to help you) - please feel free via the **edit** button underneath your post.

Comment: Thanks, Jimbo.  The post box wanted me to format that section as code, for some reason.  Possibly because I had names of objects and methods in the text.